# How to return MySQL chained Call stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 4 SP.
`get_revenue`, `get_hotel_revenue`, `get_region_revenue`, `get_division_revenue`

So `get_revenue` will first select the correct data to feed into the other 3 SP.
Below is something that I'm trying:

```
SELECT @hotel_id := hotel.hotel_id, @region_id := region_id, @division_id := division_id FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN hotel ON campaign.hotel_id = hotel.id
WHERE campaign.id = campaign_id;

#This is the part that doesnt return anything.
CALL get_hotel_revenue(@hotel_id);
CALL get_region_revenue(@region_id);
CALL get_division_revenue(@division_id);
```

But the result only returns the 3 variables.
How do I get the 3 results from the 3 nested SPs?

Here's the SP for the `get_division_revenue` which is similar with the other 2.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_division_revenue`(IN division_id INT(11))
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(revenue) FROM data
  WHERE data.property_id IN 
  (
    SELECT hotel_id FROM hotel
    WHERE hotel.division_id = division_id
  );
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second parameter as `OUT` variable:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_division_revenue`(IN division_id INT(11), OUT out_result int)
BEGIN
  -- and store the query result in that variable 
  SET out_result = (
      SELECT sum(revenue) FROM data
      WHERE data.property_id IN 
      (
        SELECT hotel_id FROM hotel
        WHERE hotel.division_id = division_id
      )
    );

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

After that, change your first stored procedure adding session variables:

```
-- Create the session variables before call procedures
set @hotel_revenue = null;
set @region_revenue = null;
set @division_revenue = null;

-- Now you can acll the procedures with those variables
CALL get_hotel_revenue(@hotel_id,@hotel_revenue);
CALL get_region_revenue(@region_id,@region_revenue);
CALL get_division_revenue(@division_id,@division_revenue);
```

Now `@hotel_revenue`, `@region_revenue` and `@division_revenue` have the result of each stored procedure as you need.

At the end of your procedure add a select with that variables:

```
SELECT @hotel_revenue as hotel_revenue, 
    @region_revenue as region_revenue,
    @division_revenue as division_revenue;
```

Comment: @resting , I edited my answer, I forgot to add the final SQL

Comment: thanks. I actually went calling in SP individually, but your solution makes sense. So the end result should be something like this: https://paste.ee/p/YP1GW ya?